# MySQL on external server, access denied to valid user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, pdo, memcached

My configuration is relatively simple. I have:

- a server running an API.
- This server connects to the database on a separate server.
- I can connect to the database from my PC using Sequel Pro by SSH to
  the API server, and then connecting to the database server from
  there.
- I can manually SSH in a terminal to the API server and connect to the
  database using the same userID and password from the MYSQL command
  line.

However when my PHP script attempts to PDO_connect I get....

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'validusername'@'%' to database 'live'' in /var/www/live/community/backend/lib/Db/Connection.php:27
Stack trace:

0 /var/www/live/community/backend/lib/Db/Connection.php(27): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=10.2...', 'validusername', 'validPass', Array)

1 /var/www/live/community/backend/lib/Communication/Base.php(57): Changers_Db_Connection->__construct('10.248.174.31', 'live', 'validusername', 'validPass', NULL)\n

2 /var/www/live/factory/index.php(40): Communication_Base->useSourceConnection('10.248.174.31', 'live_licence', 'validusername', 'validPass')

3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/live/community/backend/lib/Changers/Db/Connection.php on line 27
```

Ubuntu servers using memcached.

I am not concerned about the fatality of the error as it is pointless for the system to continue. I really need to understand why I can connect by every method except this one.

Any advice appreciated.

Regards
Chris

Comment: Egen connecting manually, did you try "use live" and to select something?

Comment: Yes, both via Sequal Pro and command line I get full access to the database and can select, insert and delete. It is just the PHP script that is denied.

Comment: Well if you're connecting through SSH from your PC, it sounds like you're forwarding the local port to your PC and connecting through that, so to the DB it looks like user@localhost. Is the server set up to allow user@%?

Comment: validusername@'%' has full permissions to the database.

Comment: Can you post the contents of PDO_connect, with usname and pwds removed of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access was restricted to known IP addresses. As such, sending 'validuser'@'%' was NOT acceptable. All other methods send 'validuser'@'API server IP address', however the PHP script sent 'validuser'@'%'. I am not 100% certain what fixed it, however in the end, I removed [Symfony 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony#Releases) and PHP 5 and re-installed.